# iOS: Delegate dilemma where delegate VC isn't directly connected to other VC

Tags: ios, delegates

In my application I have three view controllers of concern. The first contains a map and a button to open the second view controller. The second view controller contains a searchable table and then when the user selects a row it loads the relevant data in the third view controller. This all works well!

Now the intention is that when the user presses the Show on Map button in the third view controller it'll pass back the data (in this case two double values for the coordinates) to the first view controller so that the first view controller can then focus in on these coordinates.

I've followed Apple's documentation (the BirdSighting tutorial) as well as previous questions/answers on SO but I've noticed one issue.

I can't really find a place to set the thirdviewcontroller's delegate to be the first view controller. Typically I'd enter the following code in the first VC but I'm not creating an instance of the third VC - that happens in the second one:

```
thirdVC.delegate = self;  //set self as the delegate
```

So what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to pass firstVC to secondVC which can then set that as thirdVC's delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is one of many mechanisms to accomplish what you need.  The suggestion by @onnoweb is perfectly suitable, though this can get messy passing around delegate pointers.

KVO:
You can also consider KVO, putting your data into a model object, having VC3 update the model object, and VC1 an observer of those values.

NSNotificationCenter:
Another alternative is NSNotificationCenter

in VC3, use this to send a broadcast (set your dictionary to contain your latitude/longitude coordinates):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowOnMap" object:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKey:keys]];
```

in VC1:

register to receive the broadcasts:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onShowOnMap:) name:@"ShowOnMap" object:nil];
```

and handle the broadcasts:

```
-(void) onShowOnMap:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 NSDictionary *values = [notification object];
 .
 .
 . 
}
```

and unregister in your dealloc

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I'll try out the NSNotificationCenter. I'll try a few basic tutorials first so I can get a better understanding, but I'll then try out the code. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing: when it comes to the NSDictionary, should I use dictionaryWithObject:forKey:or dictionaryWithObjects as you mentioned?  I ask because I need to transfer the coordinates, but both seem to require an array. Do I make an array of the coordinate object and just transfer that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass delegate through secondViewController to thirdViewController or you can user notification center for example:

```
NSString *const NotificationDataChanged = @"NotificationDataChanged";

NSDictionary *someData = @{};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NotificationDataChanged object:someData];
```

and on the firstViewController you need to observe it, by adding for example in viewDidLoad this line :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateUserInfo:)
                                             NotificationDataChanged object:nil];

- (void)updateUserInfo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *someData = [notification userInfo];
}
```

dont forget to remove observer in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store a pointer to the first VC in you AppDelegate so that you could call

```
thirdVC.delegate =[(AppDelegate*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate firstVC];
```